# Separating dominoes pieces from one another and counting them

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, morphological-operations, object-detection

I Have a picture of Dominoes on a table, which is noisy.
I am trying to do the following:

- removing the background.
- counting how many dominoes pieces are there.
- identifying what each piece represent.
  I am using Matlab here.

I have successfully isolated the dominoes from the background using thresholding then dilatation to fill in the gaps and erosion to remove extended borders.

[image: dominoes after removing the background]

but I have no idea how to separate pieces from one another in order to count them using connected component labelling.
I have tried detecting edges using Canny's method which resulted in a noisy disconnected result.

[image: noisy result after applying Canny's]

my question is what's the correct approach to separate individual pieces.

Comment: Well that’s really cool!  Thanks for posting this. I know so little about image processing but this looks like a great one to learn on. I assume a rotationally and scale invariant correlation to a library of all possible dominoes (although the scale is less of an issue it seems since the sizes are all so similar) - interested to see what the experts post and what you end up doing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I successfully solved the problem.

for those who are curious:

- I used histogram equalization to improve shaded edges
- used a slight gaussian blur and applied thresholding to remove most of the noise
- used area opening to remove the rest of it and only keep edges that are larger in a certain threshold in surface
- used those edged to cut the binarized image

[image: edge extraction]

- after that i used watershed segmentation to separate pieces that are still connected and count them

[image: applying watershed segmentation]

Comment: It would be great to share the code.

Comment: Did you hand picked the parameters for the blurring and the elements removal? Usually those parameters are not stable between different scales etc.

Comment: @Royi yes i handpicked those, it was not a fun process I'd like to know if there is some way to automatically chose them based on some criteria

Answer (score 1):

I will sketch one way to solve:

1. The unique identifier of a piece is the separating black line. It will be easy to locate. From the number of black lines you may infer the number of pieces.
2. To segment each piece you extract the orientation of the piece from the black line of step (1). Then try to get its width by moving the same orientation in 2 opposite direction until you encounter an edge. then use this width to move in perpendicular direction. Again, until you find an edge with the width of the piece. This is the segmentation of the piece.

If you look at the edges you extracted you'd see you have what you need for step (2). For step 1 you may even use simpler methods like adaptive thresholding.

In our days it is probably the easiest to solve it using Deep Learning approaches.

Comment: that's an interesting approach.
I would like to see how it's implemented in code.
also please take a look at my solution above (or below)